# Sending transaction from a Windows application

Tags: transactions, eosio-code, windows

I want to send a transaction to EOS blockchain from my windows application.
What library do I have to put into the windows application?
And what are the preparations?

Thanks

Comment: what's your Windows application? are you using `cleos` and `keosd` or a different wallet software?

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 main options:

### Option 1

Bundle the `cleos` and `keosd` binaries with your application, so you can run them as children processes of your application and issue commands to them to manage the wallet and issue the transactions to the blockchain. That way you get a lot of nice functionality already implemented for you.

`cleos` and `keosd` documentation: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/overview-1

### Option 2

Use the HTTP API directly by sending requests to a node in the EOS network. The issue with this is that you'll have to implement more stuff yourself, like the management of the keys, building the transactions and signing them, etc. If you actually end up coding this up yourself, then it would be a good idea to make it an open source library for other windows applications to use!

Documentation of the HTTP RPC API: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/rpc.dox

### Option 3

Make your application interface with the C++ source code from the actual `cleos` and `keosd` executables. This would probably take quite a bit of work and knowledge of C/C++ and how to dissect the EOSIO source code to take the parts you need. If your windows application is coded in C/C++ then you could use the code directly, but if it's C# or something else then you would need to compile the EOSIO code separately and create native bindings to access the functionality from your code. This seems like the hardest solution to be honest.

EOSIO source code: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos